# is smape in desctools package not working?

Tags: r

In case someone is using the [desctools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DescTools/DescTools.pdf) package. Is the SMAPE not working? This:

```
MAE(predict(model, Train), Train$truth)
```

and the the other error metrics work fine but not this:

```
SMAPE(predict(model, Train), Train$truth)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SMAPE` is not an exported function from `DescTools`.
You need to use `DescTools:::SMAPE`. For example:

```
r.lm <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data=swiss)

DescTools:::SMAPE(predict(r.lm), swiss$Fertility)
# [1] 0.07711571
```

Comment: Ohh, didn't notice that so far. I will of course export the function with the next version of DescTools… Thanks for the information ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Works now:

```
 library(DescTools)
 r.lm <- lm(Fertility ~ ., data=swiss)
 SMAPE(predict(r.lm), swiss$Fertility)
 ## [1] 0.07711571
```